'History of modern art' versus 'the history of modern art'
Consider a sentence.
I love tea.
Tea here is a general idea. I like every thing that can be labeled as tea.
Consider another one.
I love green tea.
Green tea is still a general idea here. I mean that I like every thing that can be labeled as green tea.
So these two sentences both contain general ideas. The first one contains a wider idea and the second one a narrower, but generality is preserved.
Consider yet another sentence.
I love history.
Here I mean that I love everything that is related to history. Those are historical events, buildings, literature, personalities, etc. So history here is a general idea.
Consider the last one.
I love the history of modern art.
Here modern art is considered as a general idea. That is understandable. I do not refer to any specific artwork or any specific artist. Why do we use the before history here? If we consider the whole phrase the history of modern art, then I still think about a general idea that encompasses artists, artworks, curious and tragic situations, etc. I am still not specific here. For me it seems like tea and green tea. I mean it seems like two general ideas. The first idea (history) is larger than the second one (the history of modern art). So why should I use the in the last sentence? Why history of modern art isn't appropriate here?

I suppose because the history of art, like the history of England, is seen as a specific section of 'history'.

I guess It's obvious that I'm not an English speaker. I ask this question in the context of self-studying English grammar. I use "English Grammar in Use" for this purpose. The examples that I presented here resemble the examples from the book in the context of distinguishing 'something in general' from 'something specific'. That explains the origin of my question. I don't understand why we use the definite article with something that is a general idea.

We can say that 'green tea' is a specific type of 'tea'. But we don't say 'the green tea' to underline that specificity. That explains the reason why your comment doesn't explain anything for me.

Yes, I understand the reason for your question. Language usage isn't always logical; it's often 'just the way we say it'.  I was trying to suggest that 'the history of [something in particular]' is less general than 'history' as a broad topic.

Though "love the history of modern art" vastly outperforms "love history of modern art" in a Google search, neither can be seen as ungrammatical. In fact, Arnason and Prather have titled their prestigious reference work 'History of Modern Art'. In these grey areas, go with established preferences (or preferences for nearest available lookalikes). // Notice that 'I love Ceylon tea' and more literarily 'I love the tea of Ceylon' are idiomatic; 'I love the Ceylon tea' would only normally be used when referring to a well-defined sub-sub-category (eg 'that you have, and that Madge buys from ASDI').

Edwin, you were very helpful! Thanks a lot!

I love history.
History is important to me.
I love art history.
Art history is important to me.
I love modern art.
No determinatives in those.
BUT: with the x of y, you need a the.

I love the history of modern art but not all art movements.
I love modern art history.

There are often two forms in English.

attributive use of art: modern art history.
the x of y: the history of modern art.

[This answer does not take into account titles of works off art, literature, names of geographic place names etc.]

But there are exceptions. The Hill of Tara needs the article, but with 'Mull of Kintyre'  (mull an Anglicisation of a Gaelic word meaning a rounded hill or similar) the article is disallowed. And 'History of Science' is often treated as an anarthrous fixed phrase, with courses common, unlike 'the history of modern art'.

@EdwinAshworth Those are titles, this isn't. But even there, there is a the in the description: The Mull of Kintyre is the southwesternmost tip of the Kintyre Peninsula (formerly Cantyre) in southwest Scotland.  Wikipedia The examples from the OP are not titles. Titles are special cases sometimes. And when you use The Hill of Tara. there is a the. History of science is a complex subject.

But 'There are often two forms in English.' doesn't mention titles as sometimes providing exceptions or restrict to the title question; exceptions are best pointed out, or domains precised..

@EdwinAshworth That is your opinion, which, by the way, you were mistaken about.  Obviously, The Hill of Tara cannot take two the's. There are two forms in English, not taking titles into account. That precised is jarring to my ears despite what an OED might have as an entry/.

'The Hill of Tara needs the article' does not advocate two definite articles any more than ' "the Battle of Britain" needs the two capital letters' means there should be four.

@EdwinAshworth Then, why quote that to me? I think you are being unfair. I have told you the limits of my answer and you keep insisiting on,  in a kind of mean way,  all these proper names and titles, which I said I am not covering here.

I think I'll break with tradition and start DV-ing without adding a reason (not that I consider this in need of downvoting; I was merely offering additional points to give a fuller answer to the general question). I tire of such reactions.

Thanks, Lambie! I got this pattern from the Paul's answer, but was unable to formulate it in such a good way.

As @Kate Bunting suggests, the history of modern art is one subdiscipline of art history. The same kind of switch happens when we specialize, for instance,

from physics to the physics of Star Trek—which happens to be the title of a book by Lawrence Krauss,
from music to the music of Franz Haydn,
from cuisine to the cuisine of southern India,
from mathematics to the mathematics of Rubik’s cube, or
from New York City to the New York City of my childhood. Or indeed,
from New York City to the New York City I visited on a grade-school field trip in 1971.

This is simply how English works.

But while 'I love the history of modern art' certainly makes hits for the anarthrous analogue nigh-on negligible according to Google searches (using doubled inverted commas), anarthrous 'History of Science' seems to outperform 'the H/history of S/science' (though I'll admit the results can't be true, being contradictory, with "history of science"  -"the history of science" allegedly outperforming "the history of science"). But 'History of Science', often capitalised, is seen as being more unary, more coherent, nearing the open compound status many would afford 'Law of T/torts' say.

... See Huddersfield University Course and Module Catalogue.

Paul, I really appreciate your answer. I understood the pattern. I guess I will be able to use it instead of some well-defined rule.

versus: I love art history. No the. versus: Modern art is a complicated subject. No the there either.
